# Find records on group level which are connected to all other record within the group

Tags: sql, hana

I have a scenario where I have to find IDs within each group which are connected to all other IDs in the same group. So basically we have to treat each group separately.

In the table below, the group A has 3 IDs 1, 2 and 3. 1 is connected to both 2 and 3, 2 is connected to both 1 and 3, but 3 is not connected to 1 and 2. So **1 and 2 should be output** from group A. Similarly in group B only 5 is connected to all other IDs namely 4 and 6 within group B, so **5 should be output**. Similarly from group C, that **should be 8**, and from group D no records should be output.

So the output of the select statement should be 1, 2, 5, 8.

| GRP | ID | CONNECTED_TO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | **1** | 2 |
| A | **1** | 3 |
| A | **2** | 3 |
| A | **2** | 1 |
| A | 3 | 5 |
| B | 4 | 5 |
| B | **5** | 4 |
| B | **5** | 6 |
| B | 6 | 4 |
| C | 7 | 21 |
| C | 7 | 25 |
| C | **8** | 7 |
| D | 9 | 31 |
| D | 10 | 35 |
| D | 11 | 37 |

I was able to do this if group level was not required, by below SQL:

```
SELECT ID FROM <table> 
where CONNECTED_TO in (select ID from <table>) 
group by ID
having count(*) = <number of records - 1>
```

But not able to find correct SQL for my scenario. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `count` and `count(distinct)` functions as the following:

```
select id
from tbl T
where connected_to in 
(
  select id from tbl T2
  where T2.grp = T.grp
)
group by grp, id
having count(connected_to) = 
  (
    select count(distinct D.id) - 1
    from tbl D
    where T.grp = D.grp
  )
```

When `count(connected_to) group by grp, id` equals to the `count(distinct id) - 1` with the same grp, this means that the ID is connected to all other IDs.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine except in the case when connected_to has data apart from those in ID. Example, if we insert a record as ('A', 2, 5) the sql does not output 2. I guess because 5 as connected_to is not part of ID in group A

Comment: You are welcome, I updated the answer to cover this issue, see this demo on MySQL https://dbfiddle.uk/4M_T-tzO

Comment: I have a slight change in logic here. 1 connected_to 2, automatically means that 2 is connected to 1 without any additional rows saying so.  For, example if data is like ('A', 1, 2) , ('A', 2, 3) 

This means 1 is connected to 2 and also 2 is connected to 1. So, result should be both IDs 1 and 2 here. How can we tweak your query for a efficient solution? I tried but my sql became very big. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One option is to union the id and connected_to then apply the same query, if I understood your requirement correctly this will help you https://dbfiddle.uk/UvEtjPEY